# Android development, retrieving values from a string array

Tags: android

I have this array in my xml

```
<string-array name = "locations">
    <item value = "KDLH">Duluth International Airport</item>
    <item value = "KBJI">Bemidji</item>
    <item value = "KAUM">Austin Municipal</item> 
    <item value = "KBDE">Baudette International Airport</item>
    <item value = "KBBB">Benson Municipal</item>  
    <item value = "KCBG">Cambridge Municipal</item>
    <item value = "KCQM">Cook Municipal Airport </item>
    <item value = "KCOQ">Cloquet</item> 
    <item value = "KTOB">Dodge Center Airport </item>
    <item value = "KEVM">Eveleth</item>
    <item value = "KLXL">Little Falls</item>
    <item value = "KMML">Marshall</item>
    <item value = "KANE">Minneapolis / Blaine </item> 
    <item value = "KLVN">Minneapolis, Airlake Airport</item>
    <item value = "KMSP">Minneapolis-St. Paul</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value when an item is selected and not the text. How do I go about doing this? Currently I'm only able to retrieve the text by doing this. I can only currently retrieve the selected text and not the value attribute.

Comment: do you want to get value ?

Comment: @Rstar That's what he has mentioned :D

Comment: @user2293498, `item` tag has no `value` attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really a great solution for this.  Here's how I normally do it.

```
<string-array name="locations">
    <item>Duluth International Airport</item>
    <item>Bemidji</item>
    <item>Austin Municipal</item>
    <item>Baudette International Airport</item>
    <item>Benson Municipal</item>
    <item>Cambridge Municipal</item>
    <item>Cook Municipal Airport </item>
    <item>Cloquet</item>
    <item>Dodge Center Airport </item>
    <item>Eveleth</item>
    <item>Little Falls</item>
    <item>Marshall</item>
    <item>Minneapolis / Blaine </item>
    <item>Minneapolis, Airlake Airport</item>
    <item>Minneapolis-St. Paul</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="location_values">
    <item>KDLH</item>
    <item>KBJI</item>
    <item>KAUM</item>
    <item>KBDE</item>
    <item>KBBB</item>
    <item>KCBG</item>
    <item>KCQM</item>
    <item>KCOQ</item>
    <item>KTOB</item>
    <item>KEVM</item>
    <item>KLXL</item>
    <item>KMML</item>
    <item>KANE</item>
    <item>KLVN</item>
    <item>KMSP</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you can just pull the value from the `location-values` array.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like McCracken's answer better, you COULD store each pair with some special formatting that you could later parse.

Example:

```
<string-array name = "locations">
    <item>KDLH:Duluth International Airport</item>
    <item>KBJI:Bemidji</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

And then:

```
String location = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations)[index];
String[] pieces = location.split(":");
String code = pieces[0]; // KDLH
String name = pieces[1]; // Duluth International Airport
```